# Numbering IDs based on group R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-munging, ids

I have the `dataframe` below called `df1`. I'd like to assign an ID based on as soon as it approaches 'Apple', it changes the ID number to the next ordinal number. When it's assigned 'Apple', I want all the corresponding labels after to be what was assigned for 'Apple'. But as soon as 'Apple' comes up, it goes up a number as with the following labels.

Thanks and much appreciated!

```
df1 <- data.frame (fruit_name  = c("Apple", "Banana", "Cherry",
                           "Orange", "Blueberry", "Peach",
                           "Apple", "Banana", "Cherry",
                           "Orange", "Blueberry", "Peach",
                           "Apple", "Banana", "Cherry",
                           "Orange", "Blueberry",
                           "Apple", "Cherry"))
```

into the following

```
df2 <- data.frame (ID  = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2",
                           "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3",
                           "4", "4"),
                   fruit_name = c("Apple", "Banana", "Cherry",
                                  "Orange", "Blueberry", "Peach",
                                  "Apple", "Banana", "Cherry",
                                  "Orange", "Blueberry", "Peach",
                                  "Apple", "Banana", "Cherry",
                                  "Orange", "Blueberry",
                                  "Apple", "Cherry"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rowid`

```
library(data.table)
df1$ID <- rowid(df1$fruit_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cumsum`

```
df1$ID <- cumsum(df1$fruit_name == 'Apple')
```